# How to get the ASCII value of a string

Tags: c#-4.0

Suppose there is a string:

```
String str="Hello";
```

HOw can i get the ASCII value of that above mentioned string?

Comment: ASCII value of a char or of the string ?

Comment: What *exactly* are you looking for? The ASCII-encoded binary data for the text? ASCII values for each individual character in some other form?

Comment: @JonSkeet actually i want to break a whole string into individual characters and than i want to sort them on the basis of their ASCII values.

Comment: @Thomas ASCII value of a Char as well as ASCII value of a whole string

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
byte[]  asciiBytes =Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str);
```

You now have an array of the ASCII value of the bytes

Answer (score 1):

Given your comment, it sounds like all you need is:

```
char[] chars = str.ToCharArray();
Array.Sort(chars);
```

A `char` value in .NET is actually a UTF-16 code unit, but for all ASCII characters, the UTF-16 code unit value is the same as the ASCII value anyway.

You can create a new string from the array like this:

```
string sortedText = new string(chars);
Console.WriteLine(chars);
```

As it happens, "Hello" is already *in* ascending ASCII order...